# (C) code cant work with all wanted conditions

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TEN 10 
int main ()
{
 int number = 0;
 int digit = 0;
 int last_digit = 0;
 int digit_sum = 0;
 int i = 0;
while (i == 0)
{
 printf("Please Enter A Positive Number! \n"); //explaining
 scanf("%d",&number);
 if (number > 0)
{
    i++;
}

}

    while (number > 0)
    {
    digit = number % TEN; //breaking number into digits
    number /= TEN;

    if (last_digit != digit) //comparing digits
    {
       last_digit = digit;
       digit_sum += digit;
    }


    }


    printf("The Sum Of The Digits Is : %d",digit_sum);
    return 0;
```

}

---

the code will divide the number into digits and check if there are duped digits, in case there are, only one of them will be calculated for exmple: 3211
3+2+1, but my problem is thats the code wont work with numbers like 31211 Im thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: One possible solution is to read the input as a string, sort it (so e.g. `"31211"` becomes `"11123"`) and remove consecutive duplicates (so the string `"11123"` becomes `"123"`) and then do the summing.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, take the tour to learn what questions to ask and how. Here there is no question. Also, please indent code properly when you post here.

Comment: can you give me an exmple?

Answer (score 2):

The code doesn't work because there is no guarantee that duplicate's will appear consecutive manner. your code handles that not the other ways. That's why it fails.

A simple solution would be to consider a 10 element array where you will keep count of which element appeared and which didn't.

The idea is to map the digits to the array indices of the 10 element array. Intialized with `0`.

```
...
int digitAppeared[10]={0};
while (number)
{
    digit = number % TEN; //breaking number into digits
    number /= TEN;
    digit_sum  += (1 - digitAppeared[digit]) * digit;
    digitAppeared[digit] = 1;
}
...
```

To give you a clear idea this line basically checks whether the element appeared or not and as per the result it will add the digit.

If digit `D` appeared then `digitAppeared[D]=1`
        and if it didn't then `digitAppeared[D]=0`.

We will add it to digitsum if it appears first time. That's why the `(1-digitAppeared[D])` will tell us whether to add it or not.

```
    digit_sum  += (1 - digitAppeared[digit]) * digit;
```

Comment: so can i fix it in so it`ll work with unconsecutive  manner? I have been trying to fix that. (I have Noticed that)

Comment: @SaKaMoToSaN15.: Yes you can. Just conmsider taking an array an do it. keep track of elelemts.

Comment: Sorry if im kind of nagging im a begginer so i dont realy know how use array`s is there a way to do it without arra`ys?

Comment: @SaKaMoToSaN15.: Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to string use itoa() . sort it and then  walk through it , looking for unique number and do your calculation

Comment: Note that `itoa` is not a standard C function, it might not be available everywhere.

Comment: Ok no problem then creating an array out of number is one option. 32222
 -> [3,2,2,2] then do the calculation

Answer (score 0):

You can mark which digits were already added by using setting logical flags as represented by `done` in program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TEN 10 
int main ()
{
 int number = 0;
 int digit = 0;
 int last_digit = 0;
 int digit_sum = 0;
 int i = 0;
 int done[10];
while (i == 0)
{
 printf("Please Enter A Positive Number! \n"); //explaining
 scanf("%d",&number);
 if (number > 0)
{
    i++;
}

}
    memset(done,0,sizeof(done));
    while (number > 0)
    {
    digit = number % TEN; //breaking number into digits
    number /= TEN;
      if(done[digit] == 0)
      {
       digit_sum += digit;
       done[digit] = 1;
      }
    }


    printf("The Sum Of The Digits Is : %d",digit_sum);
    return 0;
}
```